# Regular expression to match a particular url and to extract a specific character from it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a url with below format:

```
https://ab.efghix.com/1234567890/f231a8c9ef2008b1d8772c27c359211fa-c0l
```

I need to split this url and have to extract the last character from `f231a8c9ef2008b1d8772c27c359211fa` which is `a` in this example. I want to do this using a regex, for which i tried following pattern:

```
ptn = /^.*((ab.efghix.com\/)|(^\d{10}$))\??([^-\?]*).*/
url = "https://ab.efghix.com/1663215071/f231a8c9ef2008b1d8772c27c359211fa-c0l"
ptn.match(url)
```

For which i am getting response as below:

```
 <MatchData "https://ab.efghix.com/1663215071/f231a8c9ef2008b1d8772c27c359211fa-c0l" 
  1:"ab.efghix.com/" 
  2:"ab.efghix.com/" 
  3:nil 
  4:"1663215071/f231a8c9ef2008b1d8772c27c359211fa" >
```

I need help in fine-tuning this pattern to obtain the last character of fourth `MatchData`. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You can use your current regex and then take the last character of the match using ruby: `ptn.match(url)[4][-1]` can't you?

Comment: I want to get the last character through regex directly as a matched array element

Comment: You misused `^` and `$` anchors and alternation. Almost you need [`ab\.efghix\.com\/\d{10}\/[^-]*(.)-`](http://rubular.com/r/VRvaiGKJ6G) which stores desired character in capturing group one.

Comment: if you start by parsing the URL with `require 'open-uri' ... uri = URI(url)`, you can simplify your Regex a lot, reading only `uri.path`.

Comment: @Phlip, Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other possibilities, you could use

```
.*(\w)-[^-]*$
```

and take the first group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/bWdekO/3/).

---

This says:

```
.*     # consume everything up to the end
(\w)   # a word character: 0-9A-Za-z_
-      # a dash
[^-]*  # not a dash, 0+ times
$      # anchor it to the end
```